# Why 't Hooft anomaly can be described by some characteristic class?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, cohomology

In some recent papers, such as Zohar [PhysRevB.97.054418](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.054418.), Zohar [arXiv:1705.04786](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04786), Metlitski [PhysRevB.98.085140](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.98.085140), the authors state that the anomaly inflow term/ topological action can be expressed in cocycles, and these terms have the form like $\int A\wedge w_{2}$, where $A$ is the gauge field associating with the global symmetry involved in mixed 't Hooft anomaly, $w_{2}$ is the second Stiefel-Whitney class.

I don't know why 't Hooft anomaly can be described by these characteristic class, are there references for this method? And I can't find this method in David Tong's gauge theory lecture notes, Nakahara's book, or some quantum field theory book.

Comment: The first link is broken. Should it point to [Walls, anomalies, and deconfinement in quantum antiferromagnets](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.054418) (also on the arXiv as https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05731)?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Yes.